# how do I send the last insert id data to another function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, last-insert-id

I want to pass my last insert id from one table into another function when I test with var_dumb() $ids var contains value but after submiting $ids var contains nothing.
can someone show me how to do it in this code,
thank you

this is my controller :

```
function save()
{
    $judul = $this->input->post('judul');
    $isi = $this->input->post('isi');
    $kategori = implode(',', $this->input->post('kategori'));
    $c_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $data = array(
        'judul' => $judul,
        'isi' => $isi,
        'kategori' => $kategori,
        'publish' => $c_date
    );

    $ids = $this->text_editor_model->simpan($data);
    redirect('text_editor');

    $last = $this->upload_image($ids);
}

function upload_image($last)
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './berkas/news/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = 0;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    var_dump($last);

    if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        $this->output->set_header('HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error');
        exit;
    } else {
        $file = $this->upload->data();
        $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
            ->set_output(json_encode(['location' => base_url().'/berkas/news/'.$file['file_name']]))
            ->_display();
        $count = count($file['file_name']);
            for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
                $data2[$i]['id_berita'] = $last;
                $data2[$i]['img_name'] =  $file['file_name'];
            }
            $this->text_editor_model->insert_img($data2);
            exit;
    }
}
```

my simpan model :

```
function simpan($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('db_news',$data);

    $id_berita = $this->db->insert_id();
    return $id_berita;
}
```

Comment: where is `simpan()` method?

Comment: simpan is my model

Comment: does `redirect('text_editor');` redirect to another page?if it does then `$last = $this->upload_image($ids);` will not execute

Comment: move `redirect('text_editor');` after `upload_image()`

Comment: is `save()` called by an ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

if `redirect('text_editor');` redirects to another page? then $`last = $this->upload_image($ids);` will not execute, so you need to call the upload first then redirect

```
$last = $this->upload_image($ids);
redirect('text_editor');
```

Comment: if i write this, tinymce text editor image dispay error 'Failed to upload image: HTTP Error: 500'

Comment: that means the upload function is executing and `$this->upload->do_upload('file') ` is false

Comment: if i erase 'function image_upload($last){' to only 'function image_upload(){' and '$data2[$i]['id_berita'] = $last;' to '$data2[$i]['id_berita'] = 1;' or another certain value it will works, why ?

Comment: are you sure you have `$ids` is a string/number?

Comment: yes i'm sure, i think the problem is in json encode